# Should Interface implementations be independent

Tags: oop, design-patterns, ooad

I have come across some legacy code that has raised all my heckles as an  Object Oriented Programmer.

Here's the pattern used often:
**An interface has two implementations and one implementation calls a method of the other.**

Now, I think it should be refactored so that the implementations do not know about each other. It is simple enough HOW to do it. What I cannot figure out clearly - & hoping good people of SO would help me with -  is WHY.

I can see the theoratical reason - it is a terrible object-oriented design. But I am playing the devil's advocate here and asking - what is the practical disadvantage of two implementation having knowledge of each other. Why should time & money be spent to get rid of this (in my mind) anti-pattern?

Any info or links on this will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like versioning is taking place.  For compatibility reasons, you can't just change an interface; you will break all of the clients.  So, you create a new version of the interface with the additional new members, and duplicate all of the original ones, calling the original interface methods in turn.  Might not be the best way to do it, but it is a way, and it does have the virtue of being expedient.

Comment: A good question, but doesn't seem to really belong in the SO format--this is definitely more of a solicitation for opinions, and as much as I would like to see some of those opinions, I think it violates intent.

Comment: "It is a terrible object-oriented design" is not a (theoretical, whatever that means) reason for getting rid of it, it's a blanket statement with no supporting reasoning.

Comment: Does the one inherit from the other? Otherwise this doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Brian Warshaw: I wanted to make sure it *did* belong to SO format, that's why I used the tags design, good-design, design-patterns etc. Essentially it is not opinions but practical good/bad effects of doing something a certain way, hence I thought the question did belong in SO :-). Hope you agree.

Comment: @dmckee: No, one does not inherit from the other. It is a situation of Animal inteface being implemented by Dog & Cat classes. Dog.eat() does some processing & then calls Cat.eat().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with an implementation1 of interface1 being aware of or interacting with implementation2 of interface1.

I think you have just spotted an intended or un intended implementation of proxy pattern 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for the link. This explains exactly what i had (with the reasons for doing it the way it did!)

Answer (score 2):

> I can see the theoratical reason - it is a terrible object-oriented design.

Why? It sounds entirely reasonable to me.

For example, suppose I want to *decorate* every call - e.g. to add statistics for how often a call has been made, or add some authorization check etc. It makes sense to keep that decoration separate from the *real* implementation, and just delegate:

```
public class DecoratedFoo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IFoo original;

    public DecoratedFoo(IFoo original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    } 

    public string Bar() // Defined in IFoo
    {
        // Update statistics here, or whatever
        return original.Bar();
    }
}
```

Why do you view that separation of concerns to be "terribly object-oriented design"? Even if the decorated class knows about a *specific implementation* of `IFoo` and calls members which aren't part of `IFoo` itself in order to make things more efficient, it doesn't seem particularly awful to me. It's just one class knowing about another, and they happen to implement the same interface. They're more tightly coupled than the example above which *only* knows about `IFoo`, but it's still not "terrible".

Comment: Jon, that's interesting. My thoughts were mainly about readability and maintenance. Since which imlplementation is used by whom is all done through Spring injection, we have one implementation injected into the other. It just makes trying to follow logic threads pretty difficult.

Comment: @OceanBlue: My experience is exactly the opposite - I've found it makes it much simpler to separate out genuine business logic in the "core" implementation from non-functional requirements around statistics gathering.

Answer (score 0):

That method of the "other implementation" that the first implementation calls is what I would call a library function.  Put it in a separate module/file/project/whatever (depends on your language/dev env) and have both implementations include it and use it from there.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with two implementations of some interfacing containing common code, but of course that common code should probably be separated from each implementation so that you can load either into your program without having to load the other.

Comment: Sure. That would be one way of doing it. Or else Having a base class with common code that both extensions can use. The issue is not how to do it. The question is it bad to have two implementation of an interface have knowledge about each other?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on this are

1. Suppose in the due course of time if you are retiring one implementation and you have kept that separately then there is no change in the other and you dont need to test that. If there is no separation you need to spend time in separating and testing the other implementation.
2. Its always cleaner to have single responsibility.